# Package and run spring boot tests from jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit5

I need to run some spring based automated tests in a docker container. The tests are junit5 based. I cannot use maven test as it's not available in the container so i'm looking at packaging the tests project as a single fat jar and run the tests via java -jar . I created a small spring boot application that calls the junit tests. I'm also using the maven assembly plugin to package everything into a single jar. Everything is working fine in my IDE but when I run the jar file i'm getting null pointer errors. It also looks like the app is unable to find my application.yml which is in the root level.

I also created a spring.factories file to include the spring test listeners
I don't have a src/main/java. These files all reside under src/test/java.

One of my sample test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TestClass {
  
  @Autowired
  private BeanA beanA;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

My main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestRunnerApp implements CommandLineRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SmokeTestsRunnerApp.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) {

    SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
        .selectors(selectClass(TestClass.class)))
        .build();
    Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
    TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);
    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
    launcher.execute(request);

    TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
    summary.printFailuresTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    summary.printTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));

    if (summary.getTotalFailureCount() > 0) {
      System.exit(-1);
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
               <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/test/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <mainClass>my.test.package.TestsRunnerApp</mainClass>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

assembly.xml

```
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>fat-tests</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/spring.factories</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring.factories</source>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.class</include>
                <include>**/*.yml</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

spring.factories

```
org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener = \
    org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener,\
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener,\
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener,\
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener,\
    org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener
```

when I run the jar file that was created, it doesn't set the profile i specified via the application.yml or load up values needed for my configuration files. I tried manually specifying the file via --spring.config.location but that didn't work either. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? is this approach even possible to run the tests?

Comment: Please explain this: `I need to run some spring based automated tests in a docker container.` more in detail...why can't you run those tests outside of a docker container?